# .htaccess redirect domain to sub domain with keep file name and params

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want use .htaccess to redirect these examples:

```
example.com
example.com/forum
www.example.com
www.example.com/forum
```

to this:

```
forum.example.com
```

I write this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^forum\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://forum.example.com [R=301,L]
```

It's good but I want keep file name and params in url. so I change it to this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^forum\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://forum.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It's ok, and for example when I goto this url:

```
http://example.com/viewforum.php?f=2
```

redirect to:

```
http://forum.example.com/viewforum.php?f=2
```

But when I goto this:

```
http://example.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=2
```

redirect to this:

```
http://forum.example.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=2
```

but this target url is not correct and must be like this:

```
http://forum.example.com/viewforum.php?f=2
```

How can fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^forum\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:forum\/)?(.*)$ http://forum.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```